# write data to csv | python

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

Need advise, on how we can write the output data to csv file.

```
output_data=
('6138', ['Test_storage_esx01', '07-22-2021', '01.30.00.0528'], 'policy1', 'Completed')
('6139', ['Test_storage_esx03', '07-22-2021', '02.30.00.0536'], 'policy1', 'Completed')
('6141', ['Test_storage_esx05', '07-22-2021', '04.00.00.0655'], 'policy1', 'Completed')
('6140', ['Test_storage_esx04', '07-22-2021', '03.00.00.0537'], 'policy1', 'Completed')
('6141', ['Test_storage_esx05', '07-22-2021', '04.00.00.0655'], 'policy1', 'Completed')
('6131', ['Test_storage_esx01', '07-22-2021', '22.00.00.0550'], 'policy1', 'Completed')
('6139', ['Test_storage_esx03', '07-22-2021', '02.30.00.0536'], 'policy1', 'Completed')
('6139', ['Test_storage_esx03', '07-22-2021', '02.30.00.0536'], 'policy1', 'Completed')
```

Tried below but it's now working

```
with open('output.csv', "wb") as csv_file:
   writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
    writer.writerows(output_data)
```

```
expected csv file output-
 ID      Storage          date       time         policy  status
6138 Test_storage_esx01 07-22-2021 01.30.00.0528 policy1 Completed
6139 Test_storage_esx03 07-22-2021 02.30.00.0536 policy1 Completed
6141 Test_storage_esx05 07-22-2021 04.00.00.0655 policy1 Completed
6140 Test_storage_esx04 07-22-2021 03.00.00.0537 policy1 Completed
6141 Test_storage_esx05 07-22-2021 04.00.00.0655 policy1 Completed
6131 Test_storage_esx01 07-22-2021 22.00.00.0550 policy1 Completed
6139 Test_storage_esx03 07-22-2021 02.30.00.0536 policy1 Completed
6139 Test_storage_esx03 07-22-2021 02.30.00.0536 policy1 Completed
```

Comment: Can you provide expected content of `output.csv`?

Comment: Added expected content of output.csv

Comment: What is output_data? Is it a list of tuples? It's not a valid Python structure currently

Comment: @TrueEntertainer I have posted a comprehensive answer to your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few problems with your code, firstly you need to restructure your `output_data` variable to be a list of lists instaed of a list of tuples as this isnt a valid datatype for writing to csv's. Then you need a header list for your headings, and in the open statement use the `w` mode instead of `wb` as you can not write strings to the file in `wb` mode

**The code:**

```
import csv
header = ['ID','Storage','date','time','policy','status']
output_data = [
    ['6138', 'Test_storage_esx01', '07-22-2021', '01.30.00.0528', 'policy1', 'Completed'],
    ['6139', 'Test_storage_esx03', '07-22-2021', '02.30.00.0536', 'policy1', 'Completed'],
    ['6141', 'Test_storage_esx05', '07-22-2021', '04.00.00.0655', 'policy1', 'Completed'],
    ['6140', 'Test_storage_esx04', '07-22-2021', '03.00.00.0537', 'policy1', 'Completed'],
    ['6141', 'Test_storage_esx05', '07-22-2021', '04.00.00.0655', 'policy1', 'Completed'],
    ['6131', 'Test_storage_esx01', '07-22-2021', '22.00.00.0550', 'policy1', 'Completed'],
    ['6139', 'Test_storage_esx03', '07-22-2021', '02.30.00.0536', 'policy1', 'Completed'],
    ['6139', 'Test_storage_esx03', '07-22-2021', '02.30.00.0536', 'policy1', 'Completed']
 ] 

with open('output.csv', "w") as csv_file:
    writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
    writer.writerow(header)
    writer.writerows(output_data)
```

**Output:**

```
 ID      Storage          date       time         policy  status
6138 Test_storage_esx01 07-22-2021 01.30.00.0528 policy1 Completed
6139 Test_storage_esx03 07-22-2021 02.30.00.0536 policy1 Completed
6141 Test_storage_esx05 07-22-2021 04.00.00.0655 policy1 Completed
6140 Test_storage_esx04 07-22-2021 03.00.00.0537 policy1 Completed
6141 Test_storage_esx05 07-22-2021 04.00.00.0655 policy1 Completed
6131 Test_storage_esx01 07-22-2021 22.00.00.0550 policy1 Completed
6139 Test_storage_esx03 07-22-2021 02.30.00.0536 policy1 Completed
6139 Test_storage_esx03 07-22-2021 02.30.00.0536 policy1 Completed
```

Comment: Thanks @TERMINATOR it really helps